# Laravel .htaccess not working on deployment host

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have just tried to deploy a my Laravel app to a shared hosting and it seems like the .htaccess is causing an internal server error, if I delete it all the files in /public can be accessed. I have checked several of the other answers here, but no one solved the problem. I have checked all the required modules

Comment: Have you changed your file permissions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel. Also, here is some configuration documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally looked into the hosting service's docs and in their examples it's
    `RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]`
with a trailing slash instead of just
    `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`
Don't know why but that made the difference and now works both on my localhost and the deployment host.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying your app to a shared hosting, make sure that your domain or subdomain is pointing to the public folder in your laravel application. When asked for the document root path point it to Eg.

```
/public_html/laravel_project/public
```

Try that to see if you are still facing issues

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Apache2 not letting the /public/index.php file handle/route all incoming requests...

apache.conf needed to be changed (and Apache2 restarted).

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
    AllowOverride None
```

Change to:

```
<Directory "/var/www/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
```

Restart Apache.

The following is what helped me solve this issue (I put in the htaccess_tester.php and when that started showing up, I'd solved this annoying issue).

Hope this helps someone else :-)

(https://docs.boltcms.io/5.2/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works)